# How to create/manage multiple ManagedObjectContexts?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a problem, and I'm pretty confident that I know in a broad sense what it is and how to fix it, but I'm not sure and haven't found what the clean / best practice way to implement the solution is.

My problem: I am loading some data from a file into my Core Data Model in a background thread using dispatch_async, which works fine except when I do things in the GUI that also affect the model and then bang, for example:

```
'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection ... was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

... which I assume is due to two threads messing with data in the same ManagedObjectContext, because I am only using one at the moment.

All the articles and answers I've read tell me that I should use a separate ManagedObjectContext for the background thread, but how/where to set it up?

I currently create my PersistentStoreCoordinator and (one) ManagedObjectContext in my App Delegate, and pass the ManagedObjectContext to my (only) View Coordinator. It in turn passes it to the background data load task (which is a class method of one of my model classes), thus causing the problem.

Should I

1. pass the PersistentStoreCoordinator to the View Controller, so that it in turn can pass it to the background task, so that the background task can create its own local ManagedObjectContext?
2. create a pool of ManagedObjectContexts in the App Delegate and pass all of them to the View Controller, so that it can use one itself and give others out to background tasks?
3. something else entirely?

Comment: Would you be able to add some code? Especially the code that generates the exception. You're right when you say that you should carefully manage your NSManagedObjectContext objects between threads, but it'd be really nice to see your code anyway.

Comment: I haven't managed to reproducibly create exactly the same exception as yet, the one I quoted was one example. But whenever I get problems, it is always when I am doing something in the GUI that changes something in the ManagedObjectContext, while the background task is loading & saving data in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't been able to consistently reproduce the problem; it seems to be highly timing-dependent. But here is what I have done to try to prevent it.

In the View Controller:

```
- (void) loadNewStuff: (NSString *)stuffID
{
     dispatch_async(taskQueue, 
       ^(void){[MyModelClass loadNewStuff: stuffID withContext: myContext];}
     );
}
```

In the model class:

```
+ (void) loadNewStuff: (NSString *)stuffID withContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *)passedContext
{
  NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
  [localContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: passedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];

  // load new stuff, save local context, finished

}
```

... is this ok, or am I overlooking something that is going to bite me horribly?

(I'm using ARC, so I assume not explicitly releasing the locally-created context is ok?)